# PhantomJS screenshot Trading View Chart

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, render, webpage-screenshot

I'm using PhantomJS to render a screenshot of a [Trading View chart widget](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/):

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/exatjd8w/

Trading View Chart Code:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_f0339"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_f0339"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
```

PhantomJS:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://example.com/chart_test.php', 
    function(status) {

        console.log("Status: " + status);

        if (status === "success") {
```

page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {

```
        console.log('Status: ' + status);

        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.getTime();

        $('#main-widget-frame-container iframe').on('load', function() {
            console.log('iframe loaded, now take snapshot');
            page.render('screenshot_' + time + '.png');
            phantom.exit();
        });

    });

}
```

});

The problem is, the screenshot rendered shows the chart still loading despite the code above.

How can I make PhantomJS take a screenshot of the chart after it has fully loaded?

Thank you for the help

Comment: A setTimeout will not work, because the image might take longer or even load under two seconds. Instead, you need to use an onLoad handler. Just did a quick Google search and this is what you need... http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html

After the page loads, we're still not done.  Use jQuery with PhantomJS to check if the widget iframe is done loading...

`$('#main-widget-frame-container iframe').on('load', function() { console.log('iframe loaded, now take snapshot'); 
page.render('screenshot.png');
phantom.exit();
})`

Comment: @indospace.io Thanks for your response and help! I am confused on where I add page.onLoadFinished = function(status)  do you mind showing me an example with my phantom code above? I've tried a few different things with no luck. Thanks again!

Comment: You're almost there, you must include jQuery.  Here are the details to do that...
`http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html`

Answer (score 0):

```
var webPage = require('webpage')
var page = webPage.create()
page.open('https://example.com/chart_test.php', 
    function(status) { 
    })
)
page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
    (page.evaluate(function() {
      // jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM
       var date = new Date(),
           time = date.getTime()
       $('#main-widget-frame-container iframe').on('load', function() {
          console.log('iframe loaded, now take snapshot')
          page.render('screenshot_' + time + '.png')
       })
    }))
  }
)
```

Comment: I don't have PhantomJS installed, try that and let me know.  It's pretty straightforward logic but as we all know, Javascript can be a mother!